# List out on different rows combinations of two sets of words

Tags: vba, excel, rows, excel-indirect

I have a row that is made up of two columns, each cell of this row may contain more than one word. For each combination of words in each cell of the same row I have to obtain a new row. I give a simple example:

```
Column1       Column2    
W1            W2          
W3            W4          
W5
```

from this ROW1 we have to obtain 3*2 = 6 new Rows made in this way:

```
W1            W2   -->NEWROW1  
W1            W4   -->NEWROW2  
W3            W2   -->NEWROW3  
W3            W4   -->NEWROW4  
W5            W2   -->NEWROW5  
W5            W4   -->NEWROW6
```

What is a simple macro to obtain this?

Comment: Will you ever have more columns to combine, or will it always be 2?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant way, but try something like this:

```
Sub mySub()

Dim iRow as Long
Dim iRow2 as Long
Dim iOutput as long

For iRow = 1 to Cells(1,1).End(xlDown).Row
For iRow2 = 1 to cells(1,2).End(xlDown).Row
iOutput = iOutput + 1
Cells(iOutput,3) = Cells(iRow,1)
Cells(iOutput,4) = Cells(iRow2,2)
Next iRow2
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: My first answer on here. Comments welcome. How do you indent the code properly?

Comment: I usually add four more spaces at the beginning of the line for indentation...As for your answer, it will include the title row of the columns so you may want to start your `iRow` and `iRow2` at 2 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `W1` is in A1 and the results for each pair of words are to be in two cells, this can be achieved without VBA such as formulae in Row1 of:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&1+INT((ROW()-1)/2))
```

and

```
=INDIRECT("B"&1+MOD(ROW()-1,2))
```

both copied down to suit.